# SwiftUI - Using ScrollView and nested views offset leads to a scroll issue

Tags: uiscrollview, swiftui

This code works perfect and I can scroll to the most bottom image:

```
ScrollView {
    Image("MountainWelcomBackground")
        .resizable()
        .frame(height: 300)                   
    Image("MountainWelcomBackground")
        .resizable()
        .frame(height: 300)                    
    Image("MountainWelcomBackground")
        .resizable()
        .frame(height: 300)
    Image("MountainWelcomBackground")
        .resizable()
        .frame(height: 300)                  
    Image("MountainWelcomBackground")
        .resizable()
        .frame(height: 300)              
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

But in case I use this code with offset:

```
ScrollView {
    Image("MountainWelcomBackground")
        .resizable()
        .frame(height: 300)
    Image("MountainWelcomBackground")
        .resizable()
        .frame(height: 300)
        .offset(y: 500)
```

I can't scroll to the bottom and just see bouncing effect which scroll me back to the top.

[Effect is here on the video](https://youtu.be/RS-cUDeOakg)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior. I tested in XCode 11.5 and IPhone SE simulator.

Comment: hm I have Version 11.4.1 (11E503a), let me update

Comment: @FelixMarianayagam one thing that I forget that the scrollview is a part of  ZStack

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: In that case remove ZStack and check.

Comment: @FelixMarianayagam removing ZStack does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View.offset` does not change view layout, only drawing presentation on screen, so content/size of scroll view is not changed and it scrolls as before

It is not clear your real goal, but possible solution would be to use instruments which change layout, for example most simple is

```
Image("MountainWelcomBackground")
    .resizable()
    .frame(height: 300)
    .padding(.top, 500)
```

Comment: thanks as always! I just followed [SwiftUI guide from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views) and they use  `CircleImage().offset(y: -130).padding(.bottom, -130)` code to center image over map. I use kind of the same thing but just want to be able to scroll because I have more content to display. This specific case you've provide works great. Let me change offset to padding instead if I could do it

Comment: I've added more specific detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026632/swiftui-scrollview-wont-me-scroll-to-the-bottom-because-of-minus-values-in-pa). I guess your answer fits my need depend on my question here. But I recreated another question which is more specific. thanks for help

Comment: looks like I need to handle it by myself by adding extra padding at the bottom .padding(.bottom, 220) depend of how many minus values I used totally.